# Positive combinatorial curvature - upper bound for maximal number of vertices

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, graph-theory, curvature

$Thm.:$ Let $G$ be a finite graph embedded in a sphere with $n \geq  580$ vertices and $3 \leq deg(x) < \infty $ and everywhere positive combinatorial curvature $K_G(x) > 0$ for all $x \in V(G)$, then $G$ is isomorphic to either $A_n$ or $B_n$ with $A_n$ the skeleton of a $n$-sided prism and $B_n$ the skeleton of a $n$-sided anti-prism.

This is a part of the main Theorem (Thm.1.2. b)) of Zhangs paper "A result on combinatorial curvature for embedded graphs on a surface" (2008): http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X07008953

To proove this statement one uses a Lemma, that says: If the assumptions from the Theorem above hold, then all vertices of $G$ are exactly on two disjoint cycles bounding two faces. (Lemma 3.3.)

Therefore Zhang uses that the total combinatorial curvature is 2, because $G$ is embedded is in a sphere and differentiate between (case 1:) the existence of a vertex with $K_G(x) < 1/290$ and (case 2:) the property that all vertices have $K_G(x) = 1 / 290$.

My troubles in understanding the proof are in the first case of the case-by-case-analysis.

- Until the definition of $C_{1}$ I understood the ideas but I´m not sure, how Zahng defines $C_{1}$. It´s a set of vertices of $G$ with distance $1$ to the vertices on $\partial\sigma$, but what is $y$? (Is it just another vertex in $G$?).
- Why do the embedding of $G$ and the property that $\sigma$ is a face imply that $C_{1}$ is a cycle?
- And then there is my main problem of understanding. How can you reduce the number of vertices of $C_{1}$ by analyzing the possible number of vertices on $\partial\sigma$ and in the beginning, how can you make a statement about the number of vertices on $\partial\sigma$? I looked at the structure of $G$ and a vertex $x$ with i.e. face vector $(3,3,k)$ but found out no pattern.
- Why do only some of the face vectors lead to a reducement of the number of vertices on $C_{1}$ and what happens with $(4,4,k)$?

Comment: It would be a great help if you included the definition of combinatorial curvature.